# Can't make "Enter" key call a function instead of submit page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This code works fine when I map the function to the "Ctrl" key (char code 17).  But it submits the page when I change it to the "Enter" key (code 13).  Why would this happen?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../utilities/utility.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#userInput").keyup(function(event){
                    if(event.keyCode == 17){ // <--- ***** RIGHT HERE *****
                        processInput();
                    }
                });
                flashcards_main();
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="flashcards.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="question">The question paragraph.</p>
        <p id="sub_question">sub-question</p>
        <form name="chloroForm">
            <input id="userInput" type="text">
            <input id="userSubmitBtn" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="processInput()">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

I changed the function below but I get the same problem:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#userInput").keyup(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13){
            event.preventDefault(); 
            processInput();
        }
    });

    flashcards_main();
});
```

Comment: You can use `event.preventDefault`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `preventDefault()` on the event to stop the default behaviour of the key being pressed:. You also need to use the `keypress` event:

```
$("#userInput").keypress(function(event){
    if (event.keyCode == 17 || event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        processInput();
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/2gdywym5/)

Comment: I edited my post with your suggestion but it's the same problem.  I'm using the latest version of FF.

Comment: My bad, you also need to change the event to `keypress` to make sure the event is trapped in time to stop the action.

Comment: ^^ That was it. Thanks!